# Symfony ManyToMany Form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity skill and language, speciality, platforms entity with relation ManyToMany and when I create skill I select language, speciality, platforms and form is valid and normal persist and flush in DB. But when I create language or speciality or platforms  I have error This value is not valid and in debug panel in form. Why I'm not understand, help please:

```
Message Origin  Cause
This value is not valid.    skills  Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[skills] = [0 => AngularJS, 1 => API]

Caused by:

Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException
Unable to reverse value for property path "skills": Could not find all matching choices for the given values

Caused by:

Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException
Could not find all matching choices for the given values
```

In entities I delete

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->language = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->platforms = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->specialities = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

and in language, speciality, platforms deleted too

entities:

```
class Skill
{
use Timestampable;
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \MyBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages", inversedBy="skills", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $language;

/**
 * @var \MyBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryPlatforms
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CodeDirectoryPlatforms", inversedBy="skills", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $platforms;

/**
 * @var \MyBundle\Entity\CodeDirectorySpecialities
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CodeDirectorySpecialities", inversedBy="skills", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $specialities;
```

and an example:

```
class CodeDirectorySpecialities
{
use Timestampable;
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="specialities", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $specialities;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Skill", mappedBy="specialities", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $skills;
```

and add to all entity

```
    public function __toString()
{
    return $this->string_filed_entity;
}
```

this my form

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('specialities');

            $builder->add('skills','entity',
                array(
                    'class'=>'MyBundle\Entity\Skill',
                    'property'=>'skill',
                    'multiple'=>true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                )
            );
}
```

and action

```
        $entity = new CodeDirectorySpecialities();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $skills = $entity->getSkills()->getValues();
        if(!empty($skills)){
            foreach($skills as $skill){
                $skill->addSpeciality($entity);
                $em->persist($skill);
            }
        }

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('specialities_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the html5 validator is blocking you in your forms of specialities, platforms and languages.

To add a specialities, you don't need a skill so you've to ad to your builder :

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('specialities')
        ->add('skills', , 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Skill',
            'property' => 'skill',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true
          ))
    ;
}
```

And do the same for your 2 others 'sub forms'

If you want select one or more skills when you're creating a speciality, you just have to do in your controller :

```
$entity = new CodeDirectorySpecialities();
$form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $form->getData();
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('specialities_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
}
```

Due to your Many to many relation between both, skill will be automatically updated

Comment: but I need add skill when I create specialities. They have relation ManyToMany and when I create specialities - need skills, this skills have specialities

Comment: this variant work, but I not understand why form not work if ->add('skills')

Comment: Because the form couldn't resolve your `skills` type and you have to define which entity to use for this field. It was your second "caused by" in your error message. Is this issue resolved now ? [doc link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

Comment: yes now work, I now this construction, but when I create specialities I custom add specialititi to skill
'            $skills = $entity->getSkills()->getValues();
            if(!empty($skills)){
                foreach($skills as $skill){
                    $skill->addSpeciality($entity);
                    $em->persist($skill);
                }
            }'
I seems thats not ok or not best away

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do with you code in comment. Could you update your question with more details ?

Comment: update. When I create specialities I needed this specialities add in skills or if say another word when I create specialities I needed selected skills for this specialities

Comment: now, like in answer, work . But I post this answer because maybe in doctrine have instrument for this task

Comment: Yes, Dotrine will do that like I said in my answer. Sorry dude but I don't understand your question